# Как добавить аргумент в существующий конструктор?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, hotkeys

Есть ли какое-то сочетание клавиш или иное решение для добавления нового аргумента в существующий автоматически сгенерированный конструктор?

```
public class prim {
int a;
int b;


public prim(int a) {
    this.a =  a;

}
}
```

Самый что ни на есть простой пример, можно ли, не удаляя старый конструктор, добавить туда **int b**?
Чтобы было вот так:

```
public class prim {
int a;
int b;


public prim(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
}
```

Comment: Если предложенный ответ решил вашу проблему вы можете проголосовать за него и отметить его "верным".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для добавления нового `private` поля в существующий конструктор надо выделить мышью имя этого поля, нажать `Alt+Enter` и выбрать `add constructor parametr`.

Точно работает для `AndroidStudio` и `IDEA` и только если поле объявлено как `private`.

---

Также, согласно вот [этому](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-constructors.html) можно пользоваться `Alt` + `Insert` и выбрать `constructor`. Так создастся новый конструктор.

**P.S.** Этот же вопрос на `en-SO`: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692945/shortcut-for-adding-class-field-to-existing-constructor-in-androidstudio-or-idea/34692946#34692946)

Comment: Автору нужно не с нуля создать, а проапдейтить существующие конструкторы. Проблема действительно бесячая.

Comment: @Etki, ну, вроде ещё можно было мышью щёлкнуть на новое поле класса, `Alt+Enter` нажать и вроде была опция добавить в конструктор... Вроде в `AndroidStudio` что-то такое видел...

Comment: Да, alt-enter на ура, я бы проапдейтил ответ